# php recursive function return only false

Tags: php

```
function recursiveSearchKeyByVal($array, $needle) {
  //$k = false;
  foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if( is_array($val) ) {
        $k = array_search($needle, $val);            
        if( $k ) {               
            #var_dump($k);   //<-- string(8) "12345678"      TRUE
            return $k;      //<-- bool(false)               FALSE ?????????
        } else {
           recursiveSearchKeyByVal($val, $needle);
        }
    }
  }
  return false;
}

$array = array( 'a'=>array(...), 'b'=>array( 'b1'=>array( '12345678'=>'abcdefgh' ), ...) );
var_dump( recursiveSearchKeyByVal($array, 'abcdefgh') );
```

I have this recursive function and I can't make it to return correct  value... it only returns false.

Comment: why don't u want to use `array_walk_recursive()` ?

Comment: you should do "return recursiveSearchKeyByVal($val, $needle);", so the result will go upstairs... otherwise when you call your function, it returns your number, but is ignored, and then continues the foreach, and returns false at the end...

Answer (score 1):

Heh, you call your function. When you call your function you will called again and again. But when it will return another value than false, it's been deeper than one execution.

You need something like that:

```
function recursiveSearchKeyByVal($array, $needle) {
  $k = false;
  foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if( is_array($val) ) {
        $k = array_search($needle, $val);            
        if( $k ) {               
            #var_dump($k);   //<-- string(8) "12345678"      TRUE
            return $k;      //<-- bool(false)               FALSE ?????????
        } else {
           $k = recursiveSearchKeyByVal($val, $needle);
        }
    }
  }
  return $k;
}
```

Comment: tx, but this example doesn't work.. I get the same result: false

Comment: I'm in job and i wrote this fast. Later i will try again :)

Answer (score 0):

This is working and I added the support if the value is at the very first deep of the array, like this you can find anywhere it's.

```
function recursiveSearchKeyByVal($array, $needle) {
  $k = false;
  foreach($array as $key => $val) {
    if( is_array($val) ) {
        $k = array_search($needle, $val);            
        if( !$k ) {
           $k = recursiveSearchKeyByVal($val, $needle);
        }
    } elseif ($needle == $val) {
        $k = $key;
    }
  }
  return $k;
}
```

Test here : [demo](http://phptester.net/)